# Fragment Button Issue Android

Tags: java, android, button, android-fragments

Okay before I explain I'm no expert at Android programming as of yet so please excuse me if I make a dumb question.

My code that I'm trying to implement in my Java Class is dealing with Buttons and Fragments. I would like to put a button in a Fragment Class in order to move on to a website. i.e (Facebook Instagram) but I do not know why I'm getting an error at activity = this; I would like for someone to help me and explain to me (if possible) why this is and what I can do in the future to prevent this error from happen again.

Here is the Java Code:

```
package info.androidhive.slidingmenu;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;


public class NetworksActivity extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{

ImageButton imgButtonInstagram;
ImageButton imgButtonFacebook;
Activity activity;

public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.networks_layout);
}
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, 
            Bundle saedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.networks_layout, parent, false);

    activity = this;
    imgButtonInstagram = (ImageButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imgBtnInsta);
    imgButtonFacebook = (ImageButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imgBtnFace);
    imgButtonFacebook.setOnClickListener(listener);
    imgButtonInstagram.setOnClickListener(listener);

    return rootView;
    }

private View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()){
            case (R.id.imgBtnInsta):
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse("http://instagram.com/m4lvip")));

                break ;  // add here

            case (R.id.imgBtnFace):
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/")));

                break ;// add here

        }


    }
};

@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`activity = this`  this does not refer to activity context coz `NetworksActivity extends Fragment`.

Use

`activity = getActivity()`.

`getActivity()`

Return the Activity this fragment is currently associated with.

Also your imports are not right

Remove this

```
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
```

Use

```
import android.view.View
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```

Also use @Override Annotation

```
 @Override 
 public void onClick(View v) {
```

Also remove this

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Also remove this

```
implements OnClickListener
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
activity=getActivity();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the working code with Raug annotations though I didn't use neither

> Remove this
>   import android.content.DialogInterface;
>   import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener; 
>   Use
>   import android.view.View
>   import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;


public class MiscFragment extends Fragment {
ImageButton imgButtonTwitter;
ImageButton imgButtonFacebook;

public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_misc, container,
            false);
    imgButtonTwitter = (ImageButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.iButton1);
    imgButtonFacebook = (ImageButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.iButton2);
    imgButtonFacebook.setOnClickListener(listener);
    imgButtonTwitter.setOnClickListener(listener);  
    return rootView;
}
private View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()){
            case (R.id.iButton1):
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse("http://instagram.com/")));

                break ;

            case (R.id.iButton2):
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/")));

                break ;

        }


    }
};
```

}